# how can we create textboxes in php

Tags: php, html

I want to add two text boxes and a Submit button to a HTML form and Invite the user to enter a first name and surname. When the button is clicked, i want to display the first name and surname in the textboxes using php code.
i just need help in displaying the values that user inputs in the textboxes using php code. the rest is working fine.

note: html and php are in the same file.
my code is :

```
    <?PHP

        if(isset($_POST["submit1"])){

        <input type="text" value="$_POST['firstname']">;
        <input type="text" value="$_POST['surname']">;
    }

    ?>
     <form name="exercise1" method="post" action="exercise1.php">

    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="enter first name">
    <input type="text" name="surname" value ="enter surname">
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="login">

    </form>
```

Comment: Since the file is called `exercise` there ought to be some text surrounding it. Have you tried going through your book / tutorial series step by step?

Comment: @ccKep I agree, asking for the answer doesn't help you to learn or understand the programming language. Even on a basic level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the value of the same inputs, you can do that by checking if $_POST['firstname'] and $_POST['surname'] are set:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : ''); ?>" />
<input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['surname']) ? $_POST['surname'] : ''); ?>" />
```

or if you don't want inline you could set it blank by default and use that:

```
<?php
$firstname = 'enter first name';
$surname = 'enter surname';

if(isset($_POST["submit1"])) {
  $firstname = (!empty($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : $firstname);
  $surname = (!empty($_POST['surname']) ? $_POST['surname'] : $surname);
}
?>

<form name="exercise1" method="post" action="exercise1.php">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" />
  <input type="text" name="surname" value ="<?php echo $surname; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="login" />
</form>
```

if you want to add 2 more inputs with the values that were entered only after the submit button was click, just place the inputs between php "if check". Also is best to check if they exist and/or are empty (empty function automatically, first checks if the variable is set then if it's empty, so you don't have to use isset() anymore):

-------------------- EDIT --------------------

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) { ?>
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo (!empty($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : ''); ?>" />
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo (!empty($_POST['surname']) ? $_POST['surname'] : ''); ?>" />
<?php } ?>

<form name="exercise1" method="post" action="exercise1.php">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="enter first name" />
  <input type="text" name="surname" value ="enter surname" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="login" />
</form>
```

Comment: tried, it says: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\exercise1.php on line 11"

Comment: you didn't copy something right ... try again using the edit part

Comment: thank u so much, but could u plz explain this to me "<?php echo (!empty($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : ''); ?>". i cant actually understand the ? : and ' '. what are they for? the rest i understand, but not the ? : and ' ' . it will be really helpful for me. thanks.

Comment: that is called [**ternary operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) and is a short way (inline) to do: `if (condition) { true } else { false }` ... `(condition ? true : false)`. for more info search for "ternary operator". what i've done there you can roughly translate in: `if (!empty($_POST['firstname'])) { echo $_POST['firstname']; } else { echo  ''; }` but instead of writing a long line of `if ... else ...` i prefer the shorter version, for this kind of situations. good luck!

Comment: if this is what you were looking for and answered your question, please mark as accepted answer. To do that press the "v" sign under the voting system on the left side of the answer. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?PHP

        if(isset($_POST["submit1"])){

        echo '<input type="text" value="'.$_POST['firstname'].'">';
        echo '<input type="text" value="'.$_POST['surname'].'">';
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: i tried, but it says: "( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'firstname' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\exercise1.php on line 15"

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="exercise1" method="post" action="exercise1.php">
<?php

   if(isset($_POST["submit1"])){
?>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['surname']; ?>">
<?php
   }else {
?>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="enter first name">
    <input type="text" name="surname" value ="enter surname">
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="login">
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: better approach. Else,boxes are outside form and useless to further processing.

Comment: i want to display the first name and surname in the textboxes using php code after the submit button is clicked.

Comment: This code achieves this, doesn't it? First it checks wether a form has been submitted. If it does, then display the POST values in the input-fields. If it doesn't, then display the standard values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $firstname = 'Enter First Name';
  $surname = 'Enter Last Name';

 if(isset($_POST["submit1"])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
   }
 ?>
<form name="exercise1" method="post" action="exercise1.php">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="surname" value ="<?php echo $surname; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="login" />
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but i want to show first name and surname entered by user in text boxes after the submit button is clicked.

Comment: of cource it will show u firstname and lastname which submited by user. By default it shows default setting. And if page find any post submit  it will overwrite by submited values of user.